# Playwright with Figma

Tags: playwright, visual-testing

Does Playwright support Visual Testing by comparing pages with Figma designs ?

Does Playwright support Visual Testing by comparing pages with Figma designs ? We are looking for this requirement. Currently we have a requirement to perform visual testing on pages by comparing them with Figma designs. So I am looking for that solution

Comment: Playwright compares two screenshots. You can probably set the test up to first take the screenshot on your figma page and then manually modify your test to run on the page with the actual screenshot target. I don't know of any inbuilt way to accomplish this. I Imagine it will be quite finicky to match the screenshots exactly this way.